# TypeError in TestCafe Setup - Cannot Prepare Tests

Tags: testcafe, babel-polyfill

I am currently facing an issue while attempting to run TestCafe tests, and after various troubleshooting steps, I'm reaching out to the community for assistance.

Error Message:

```
    C:\Users\HeltPaaFelgen\Documents\TestCafeSystemTest>npx testcafe chrome TestSuites/Login/login.ts --test 'Valid Login'
    ERROR Cannot prepare tests due to the following error:
    

    TypeError: [BABEL] C:\Users\HeltPaaFelgen\Documents\TestCafeSystemTest\node_modules\@babel\plugin-transform-runtime\lib\babel-7\polyfills.cjs:
_index2.createPolyfillPlugins is not a function (While processing: "base$0") (While processing: "base$0")
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HeltPaaFelgen\Documents\TestCafeSystemTest\PageModels\MainPage\index.ts:4:1)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HeltPaaFelgen\Documents\TestCafeSystemTest\PageModels\Login\LoginPage.ts:5:1)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HeltPaaFelgen\Documents\TestCafeSystemTest\TestSuites\Login\login.ts:2:1)
```

Actions Taken:

- Checked Babel Plugin Versions.
- Verified Node.js Version.
- Inspected Babel Configuration (added it to the root folder).
- Updated Babel Plugins.
- Cleared Node.js Module Cache.

Versions:
TestCafe version: 3.4.0

Babel version: 7.23.6

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has insights into resolving this type of Babel-related TypeError, your guidance would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that occurs with new versions of `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`. You can track the progress on it [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/8091)

While the Testcafe team is investigating the issue, you can override the version of
@babel/plugin-transform-runtime through resolutions if you are using Yarn or through the overrides section if you are using npm.

Comment: Thank you Pavel, you'r comment is much appreciated!